# Does the Meltdown perk affect the Pulse Gun?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Pretty much what the title asks: If I've taken the Meltdown perk, will it affect the Pulse Gun? If so, does that mean I can accidentally kill/neutralize ED-E or Rex if they're too close to a robotic target I hit with the pulse gun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since it is classified as an Energy Weapon.

> ALL weapons affected by the Energy Weapons skill trigger the Meltdown if the player causes the killing blow, this is contradictory to in-game loading screens which say it affects only laser and plasma weapons.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Meltdown

Comment: It should be noted however, that the explosion triggered by Meltdown has nothing to do with the kind of weapon triggering it -  that is to say, it won't have any *special* effect on Ed-E or Rex -  just the same one it has on everyone else - a painful plasma explosion.